# Sqoop Import - Invalid Time Value with Mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I'm new to Sqoop while importing data from MySQL to HDFS, I'm getting below error,

[image: Sqoop Import Mysql Time Issue Error]

Mysql column is **Time datatype** and accepts more than 24 hours value, but while import the data from Mysql using Sqoop, i'm getting invalid TIME value error. Is there any way to skip this validation in Sqoop to import the data.

Could you help me in fixing this error?

Comment: Could you show the sqoop import statement?

Comment: Hive doesn’t have time TIME [datatype](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Intervals). So your workarounds would be converting the TIME column to string and store it in HDFS.

Comment: Import Statement:/usr/lib/sqoop/bin/sqoop-import \
  -connect "jdbc:mysql://$SOURCEHOST/$SOURCEDB?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" \
  -username $SOURCEUSER \
  -password $SOURCEPASS \
  -query "select * from $table_name where $column_name > $lastvalue AND \$CONDITIONS" \
  -hive-home $DESTINATIONPATH \
  -target-dir $DESTINATIONPATH \
  -hive-import \
  -hive-overwrite \
  -hive-drop-import-delims \
  -hive-table sify_hive \
  -null-string '\\NA' \
  -null-non-string '\\NA' \
  -m 1 2>&1 | tee "$SQOOPDESTPATH/$now/$table_name/import.log";

Comment: Hive doesn't supports that time format as @Sathishkumar has said, you should send time field as string.

Comment: @Chema it’s production database so I cannot change the column data type . Any other way to skip the validation

Comment: I think, you could cast in the query that field instead of select * , In MySQL woul be something like this: ````SELECT CAST(datetime AS CHAR)````

Comment: @Chema Excellent, sqoop import working when I use SELECT CAST(duration AS CHAR) or CONVERT(duration , CHAR). Again, when i do sqoop export the data to Mysql  these TIME data type values are not inserting.. Any solution ..

Comment: If you could show me your export statement and a row of your export data please.

Comment: @Chema /usr/lib/sqoop/bin/sqoop-export \
-connect "jdbc:mysql://$DESTHOST/$DESTDB?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" \
-username $DESTUSER \
-password $DESTPASS \
-table $table_name \
-export-dir $DESTINATIONPATH \
-input-fields-terminated-by '\001' \
-input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
-batch \
-input-null-string '\\NA' \
-input-null-non-string '\\NA' \
-m 1 2>&1 | tee "$SQOOPDESTPATH/$now/$table_name/export.log";
Data Imported correctly and in the part-000 file also having the actual data.
Actual Data : 595:16:42 & In Mysql DB : 19:16:42

Comment: What I would do in your case and it's quite common is create a stage table with all fields as strings to export the data from hdfs with sqoop, clean data if it is needed, and insert into master table with a sql statement, casting the necessary fields.